# Streaming live audio (radio) cuts out after a couple of seconds-minutes

Tags: internet, audio, flash, streaming

I am unable to listen to live streaming internet radio for more than a couple of minutes - often seconds.

Such sites include

- http://trancefm.com
- http://absoluteradio.co.uk
- http://bbc.co.uk/radio1

I have 30MB fibre optic broadband, absolutely no problems streaming (HD) video on YouTube, online gaming, or downloading files. The problem occurs at any time - not just peak hours.

I can't imagine why I only have a problem when streaming live audio. I have Flash Player version **WIN 11,1,102,55** if that's relevant, and use the latest Chrome+Firefox. The problem exists in both.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

I have contacted my provider but I get the usual "restart your router" response which I have tried; but as it appears to be *only* live audio I can't see that helping anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has **NOTHING** to do with your Internet connections. It is probably an issue on the website/radio stations' end with a poor streaming provider. Nothing you can do to fix it if the stream keeps disconnecting because of the station using a lackluster streaming system or provider.

Comment: OK thanks for your suggestion; hopefully that's the cas, even though that would be annoying. My only thought is that the sites are quite well known and established; and so I find it unlikely that (certainly the BBC) would have issues streaming content like that. I've also never experienced the problem before recently.